# Object string are appearing in the loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The object string log appearing in some pages, how can I remove this?:

```
"Tv id: 1, name: "SUPER HD", juridica: false, created_at: "2017-06-12 15:55:24", updated_at: "2017-06-12 15:55:24", points: 10>, #<Tv id: 2, name: "ULTRA HD", juridica: true, created_at: "2017-06-12 15:55:35", updated_at: "2017-06-12 15:55:40", points: 15"
```

Check the image: [image]

Comment: The answer below is most likely the solution, but would be helpful to see the code too :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `=` from your iterator, maybe you have something like:

```
<%= @variable.each do |value| %>
```

So, that's printing the `each` block, try changing it to:

```
<% @variable.each do |value| %>
```

In order to just print the content that's being iterated.

Answer (score 1):

```
<%=@variable%>
```

It Used to display values 
So u dont use

> =

in your conditions 
you use "=" below

```
<%=form_for%>
```